# C# .NetCore Okta Search for Users

Tags: okta-api

I am trying to figure out how to search for users in Okta using the SDK and .net core in C#. outside of .net core I am able to do this using Okta.Core but that is not supported in .NET Core. I can't find any documentation for doing this stuff in .NetCore using the SDK.

I can get the OktaClient connected no problem with my API token but after that I am lost now.

Anyone have an example of doing this in Core or can point me in the right direction to get documentation from Okta?

Answer (score 0):

Looking thought the Okta [documentation](https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-dotnet) I found the below code, where the client is the Okta client. Hopefully this helps:

```
Getting A User

    // have some user's ID, or login
    var someUserId = "<Some User ID String or Login>";

    // get the user with the ID or login
    var vader = await client.User.GetUserAsync(someUserId);
```

Comment: I guess I should have added about searching as well. A single user will help at the moment.